# Mahout Canopy Clustering, K-means Clustering : Java Heap Space - out of memory

Tags: hadoop, heap-memory, mahout

I'm running Mahout 0.7 on an my cluster which has 30 nodes(each has 8 cores 16G memory) trying to canopy-cluster 250000 SparseVector(300000).

If I canopy-cluster finding small number of canopy centers by tweaking canopy parameters (T1, T2), it works very well.

More then a certain number of canopy centers, **the jobs keep failing with a "Error: Java heap space" message at 67% of reduce phase.**

K-means clustering also has same heap space problems, if the value of K is increasing.

I've heard canopy-center vectors and k-center vectors are held in memory on every mapper and reducer. That would be **num of canopy center(or k) x sparsevector(300000 size) = enough for 4g memory** things, which doesn't seem too bad.

Based on previous questions here and elsewhere, I've cranked up every memory knob I can find:

- **hadoop-env.sh:** setting all the heap spaces there up to 16GB on  namenode and even 8GB on datanodes.
- **mapred-site.xml:** adding mapred.{map, reduce}.child.java.opts properties, and setting their   value to -Xmx4000m
- **mapred-site.xml:** changing mapred.tasktracker.{map, reduce}.tasks.maximum properties, and turning down their value from 8 to 4

And the problem is persisting. I've been banging my head against this for far too long -- does anyone have any suggestions?

The full command and output look something like this :

```
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

    String ratingsPath = args[0];
    String outputPath = args[1];
    String T1 = args[2];
    String T2 = args[3];

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();       

    HadoopUtil.delete(conf, new Path(outputPath));

    CanopyDriver.run(conf, new Path(ratingsPath), new Path(outputPath), new ManhattanDistanceMeasure(), 
            Double.parseDouble(T1), Double.parseDouble(T2), true, 0.0, false);

}
```

and here's error message I face :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InterruptedException: Canopy Job failed processing /MrBic/Output/SeedGeneration_predSample
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyDriver.buildClustersMR(CanopyDriver.java:363)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyDriver.buildClusters(CanopyDriver.java:248)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyDriver.run(CanopyDriver.java:155)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyDriver.run(CanopyDriver.java:170)
at MrBicClusteringDriver.main(MrBicClusteringDriver.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

2013-06-12 10:56:00,825 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntDoubleHashMap.rehash(OpenIntDoubleHashMap.java:434)
at org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntDoubleHashMap.put(OpenIntDoubleHashMap.java:387)
at org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector.setQuick(RandomAccessSparseVector.java:139)
at org.apache.mahout.math.AbstractVector.assign(AbstractVector.java:560)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.AbstractCluster.observe(AbstractCluster.java:275)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.Canopy.<init>(Canopy.java:43)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyClusterer.addPointToCanopies(CanopyClusterer.java:163)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyReducer.reduce(CanopyReducer.java:47)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyReducer.reduce(CanopyReducer.java:30)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Comment: It seems that you've tuned those java heap params... So during the execution, have you ssh to some of the datanodes and see what's going on? Say by "top" or "jmap"?

Comment: I've seen the datanode which canopy reduce runs on using nmon. There is not enough free memory. So I think this canopy-clustering algorithm in mahout needs a lot of heap memory and this is not scalable...... Is there any way to fix this problem?